# JSON.stringify, change the case of the key

Tags: javascript, json

I'm consuming a web service that returns json, and storing the json in a local variable. The json represents a simple business object such as:

```
var entry = {
  "FirstName": "John",
  "LastName": "Doe",
  ....
};
```

The casing is like that because it matches up with the property names from the .net class, as per our naming convention.

When a change a few of these properties and pass back the json, the web service now expects camel case (again, as per our naming convention for method parameters) instead of the pascal case initially returned.

```
var entry = {
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  ....
};
```

This of course doesn't work.

I'm using `JSON.stringify` to send the json back to the web service as a string, and I was looking to see if there was an easy way to change the key to camel case. However, it looks like I can only use the replacer param to work with the value.

I could change the serialization of the class, but lets pretend that's not an option. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't send the JSON back to the web service as a complex type that exactly matches the object that was originally returned (whether struct or class)? In this way the method parameter can be called pretty much anything you want, and you don't have to play with object property "renaming"?

Comment: Fix the backend. Your naming convention seems to be working against you, and creating irregularities in the naming convention, which is not what a naming convention should ever do.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use a JSON replacer to switch keys before writing.

```
JSON.stringify(myVal, function (key, value) {
  if (value && typeof value === 'object') {
    var replacement = {};
    for (var k in value) {
      if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(value, k)) {
        replacement[k && k.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + k.substring(1)] = value[k];
      }
    }
    return replacement;
  }
  return value;
});
```

For the opposite, you can use a JSON reviver.

```
JSON.parse(text, function (key, value) {
    if (value && typeof value === 'object')
      for (var k in value) {
        if (/^[A-Z]/.test(k) && Object.hasOwnProperty.call(value, k)) {
          value[k.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + k.substring(1)] = value[k];
          delete value[k];
        }
      }
      return value;
    });
```

The second optional argument is a function that is called with every value created as part of the parsing or every value about to be written.  These implementations simply iterate over keys and lower-cases the first letter of any that have an upper-case letter.

There is documentation for replacers and revivers at http://json.org/js.html :

> The optional reviver parameter is a function that will be called for every key and value at every level of the final result. Each value will be replaced by the result of the reviver function. This can be used to reform generic objects into instances of pseudoclasses, or to transform date strings into Date objects.
>
> The stringifier method can take an optional replacer function. It will be called after the toJSON method (if there is one) on each of the values in the structure. It will be passed each key and value as parameters, and this will be bound to object holding the key. The value returned will be stringified.

Comment: I'm dealing with json object until I send it back to the web service for the update, so doesn't this mean I'd have to take the json object, call stringify on it, then parse it again?

Comment: @ScottE, yeah.  Sorry I got your question backeards.  No-need to reparse.  Edited to include the stringify case.

Comment: ScottE, Mike gave you code for serializing or deserializing. You can decide which key notation you'd like to use and then use the appropriate operation. If you're using jQuery to do the ajax requests you could tell it the dataType is 'text' to avoid having the deserialization done and then do it yourself.

Comment: beautiful, thanks. As an aside, in .net using the [DataContact] and [DataMember] doesn't allow allow you to change the casing. You have to jump through some hoops - so, this is much easier.

Comment: the `value && typeof value === 'object'` condition may pass if `value` is an array, so you better complement it with `Array.isArray(value)`.

Comment: This: `if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(value, k)) {` can be shortened to this: `if (value.hasOwnProperty(k)) {`.

Comment: @Ste_95, not if `text == '{ "hasOwnProperty": 0 }')`.

Comment: Just to be explicit, to skip arrays, the `if` statement becomes `if (value && typeof value === 'object' && !Array.isArray(value)) { ... }`

Comment: Just a small tip, to explain better how your reviver works, the quoted text misses one small point.  The reviver is also called on the root object with a blank key.  MDN explains this, but your quoted Text from JSON.org doesn't.

Comment: You can use this line in TypeScript: `var replacement: Record<string, unknown> = {};`

Comment: @MikeSamuel As Eliran Malka and smbergin79 already mentioned: Your replacer function converts arrays to key-value objects. Furthermore the reviver function removes all members that are neither object nor array, and array values become `null`.