# formatting json data to be camelCased

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get a json response from the server that looks something like this:

```
{
    "Response": {
        "FirstName": "John",
        "LastName": "Smith",
        "NickNames": {
            "NameOne": "Johnny",
            "NameTwo": "JohnS",
            "NameThree": "Smithy"
        },
        "Success": true,
        "Errors": []
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can run this response through a function so that the key of each key value pair would be camelCased?

So the output would look something like:

```
{
    "response": {
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Smith",
        "nickNames": {
            "nameOne": "Johnny",
            "nameTwo": "JohnS",
            "nameThree": "Smithy"
        },
        "success": true,
        "errors": []
    }
}
```

If someone could point me in the right direction, that'd be great.

Thanks.

Comment: (Though, in the general case, you need to be wary of creating synonyms.)

Comment: Parsing it with a regular expression is problematic, likely you are better to convert it to an object, then create a new object and change the property names to start with a lower case letter, then turn it back into JSON (if that's required) or just use the new object.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You would give `JSON.parse` a reviver function that assigns values to new properties that are lower-cased.

```
function toCamelCase(key, value) {
  if (value && typeof value === 'object'){
    for (var k in value) {
      if (/^[A-Z]/.test(k) && Object.hasOwnProperty.call(value, k)) {
        value[k.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + k.substring(1)] = value[k];
        delete value[k];
      }
    }
  }
  return value;
}

var parsed = JSON.parse(myjson, toCamelCase);
```

More information about how it works [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5480605/1585).

Comment: Regarding "So if the key has at least one character…", what's the chance of an object property not having a name?

Comment: @RobG: Probably minimal for the data structure itself, but the reviver will always represent the outermost object structure as the `val` in the reviver having a key of `""`. So if I don't have the test with an `else return val;`, the result of `JSON.parse` will be `undefined`.

Comment: Why undefined? `''.toLowerCase()` just returns an empty string. Empty string is a valid property name so there's no need for the else. Unless there's a browser that supports JSON.parse but gets `toLowerCase()` wrong.

Comment: @RobG: No, I mean that when the `key` is `""`, I need to be sure to `return val`. If you don't return a value from the *reviver* function, `JSON.parse` elides that key/value pair from the result. So since the top level object has a default key of `""`, if I don't return that object, `JSON.parse` will assume that we don't want to include that object in the parsing. And since it's the outermost object, there's nothing left for `JSON.parse` to return but `undefined`.

Comment: ...notice that my reviver doesn't return any value when the `if` condition is met. That's because if I did `return val;` at that point, we'd end up with an object with both versions of the keys.

Comment: Great, haven't played with that before. Makes sense once you understand it (doh).

Comment: @1__: Your JSON is invalid. You're missing a property name before `{"Wife":...`. It should be something like `"Family": {"Wife":...`. I had to delete the entire `"Age":"12"` line because it had some invalid invisible characters in there, and you had an extra `]` near the end. After fixing your JSON, it [works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/6gxyp/). Use http://jsonlint.org/ to validate your JSON data

Comment: I think it is better version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480570/json-stringify-change-the-case-of-the-key

Answer (score 10):

The approach that user '@I Hate Lazy' suggested - using a 'reviver' function is - the right one. However his function didn't work for me.

Perhaps it is because I'm parsing a JSON array. Also I use [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/javascript_typescript.html) and it complained about a code smell :) ('not all code paths return a value'). So I ended up using a function from [another SO issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480570/json-stringify-change-the-case-of-the-key) which **did** work for me:

```
function camelCaseReviver(key, value) {
    if (value && typeof value === 'object') {
        for (var k in value) {
            if (/^[A-Z]/.test(k) && Object.hasOwnProperty.call(value, k)) {
                value[k.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + k.substring(1)] = value[k];
                delete value[k];
            }
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a functional recursive (ES6) approach.

```
function convertKeysToCamelCase(o) {
  if (o === null || o === undefined) {
    return o;
  } else if (Array.isArray(o)) {
    return o.map(convertKeysToCamelCase);
  }
  return typeof o !== 'object' ? o : Object.keys(o).reduce((prev, current) => {
    const newKey = `${current[0].toLowerCase()}${current.slice(1)}`;
    if (typeof o[current] === 'object') {
      prev[newKey] = convertKeysToCamelCase(o[current]);
    } else {
      prev[newKey] = o[current];
    }
    return prev;
  }, {});
}

// successfully tested input
const o = {
  SomeNum: 1,
  SomeStr: 'a',
  SomeNull: null,
  SomeUndefined: undefined,
  SomeBoolean: true,
  SomeNaN: NaN,
  NestedObject: {
    SomeSentence: 'A is for apple',
    AnotherNested: {
      B: 'is for blahblah'
    }
  },
  NumArray: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  StringArray: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  BooleanArray: [true, false],
  ArrayOfArrays: [[1,2,], ['a','b']],
  ObjectArray: [{Foo:'bar'}, {Hello:'world', Nested:{In:'deep'}}],
  MixedArray: [1,'a', true, null, undefined, NaN, [{Foo:'bar'}, 'wat']]
}

const output = convertKeysToCamelCase(o);

console.log(output.mixedArray[6][0].foo); // 'bar'
```

Comment: This is close, but fails on arrays of non-objects. It should be changed to:

`return (typeof o !== 'object') ? o : Object.keys(o).reduce( ... )`

Comment: @ThePants, ironic I was working on this last night. Updated this to maintain null/undefined and support array input. It still assumes your input is an array or object.

Comment: Thanks @A.X.Z, my updated answer now handles all arrays of non-objects. Tested on all kinds of input.

Answer (score 1):

@adamjyee Your solution works except for nested array of integers. A small fix could be:

```
function convertKeysToCamelCase (o) {
    if (o === null) {
      return null
    } else if (o === undefined) {
      return undefined
    } else if (typeof o === 'number') {
      return o
    } else if (Array.isArray(o)) {
      return o.map(convertKeysToCamelCase)
    }
    return Object.keys(o).reduce((prev, current) => {
      const newKey = `${current[0].toLowerCase()}${current.slice(1)}`
      if (typeof o[current] === 'object') {
        prev[newKey] = convertKeysToCamelCase(o[current])
      } else {
        prev[newKey] = o[current]
      }
      return prev
    }, {})
```

[Right to comment but lacking comment priviledge :(]

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a recursive function that traverses the tree and returns a new tree where the keys in the objects have been updated. The recursive function would call itself to deal with any sub-objects it encounters.