# using JSON.stringify() function by specifying replacer function

Tags: javascript, css, json, scripting

I use JSON.stringify(hashes), wherein this returns a json ouptut like

```
{"assets/.../.../1.css" : "3456789763456df", 
 "assets/.../.../2.css" : "345678976545678" 
  ...                   :  ...             }
```

I would like to edit the key of each key-value pair to have "/" in the beginning, i.e.. output should look like

```
{"/assets/.../.../1.css" : "3456789763456df", 
 "/assets/.../.../2.css" : "345678976545678" 
  ...                   :  ...             }
```

Notice the "/" prepended to the key of each key-value pair.

Could this be achieved using JSON.stringify(hashes, replacer) and defining a replacer function ??

Comment: Is this what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480570/json-stringify-change-the-case-of-the-key

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```js
var input = {
    "assets/.../.../1.css": "3456789763456df",
        "assets/.../.../2.css": "345678976545678"
};
var output = {};
$.each(input, function(key, value){
    output['/' + key] = value;
});

alert(JSON.stringify(output));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This is for Javascript:

```
var input = {
    "assets/.../.../1.css": "3456789763456df",
        "assets/.../.../2.css": "345678976545678"
};
var output = {};
for(var name in input) {
    output['/' + name] = input[name];
}
for(var name in output) {
    alert(name);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why do you need jQuery for this?

Comment: This is for debug, convert data to string.

Comment: Let me rephrase: You don't need jQuery for this.

Comment: Yes, I don't need a jquery for this. My question is how can i write a replacer function for this so i can use: JSON.stringify(hashes, replacer);