# Is there a way to convert property names to lower case when deserializing a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I don't have control of the web service I'm calling. It returns JSON with capitalized property names. This bothers me.

Are there any Angular plugins that will fix this? Or is there an easy and efficient way of doing so in javascript?

Comment: I don't have access to the web service, so I can't fix it there.

Comment: This is a better answer to your problem then the one in the duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/a/5480605/5157454

Comment: Voting to reopen because the other question is about changing the case of the properties of an existing object, and this one is about deserializing JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use pass a `reviver` function as an argument to [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```js
JSON.parse('{"Test": {"Foo": 1, "Bar": 2} }', function(prop, value) {
  var lower = prop.toLowerCase();
  if(prop === lower) return value;
  else this[lower] = value;
});
```

Basically, it converts each property to lower case, and checks if it's different. If it is different, it sets the lowercase property and returns undefined, thus removing the non-lowercase one. If they are equal, it returns the value, so nothing special is done.

Comment: note that to integrate with `$http` would need to put this in a `$httpInterceptor`

Answer (score 2):

Javascript Object class has a method called keys(). You can use it to iterate through your object property names and to edit them using toLowerCase() after you've converted the JSON string to a javascript object.

```
var obj = {"Test": "foo"};
var ar = Object.keys(obj);
for(var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++){
    var upperCasePropertyName = ar[i];
    ar[i] = ar[i].toLowerCase();
    obj[ar[i]] = obj[upperCasePropertyName];
    delete obj[upperCasePropertyName];
}
```