# A good way to deserialize JSON in a case-insensitve manner

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm just trying to do the most trivial thing in the world, and am running into an issue parsing inconsistently cased data from various legacy devices.

I'm trying to parse the following JSON in TypeScript

```
{
    "property": 5
}
```

vs.

```
{
   "Property": 5
}
```

The best answer I've been able to think of is literally just loop through the keys of the object and run "toUpper" on them, but is there a decent NPM package out there (like json-typescript-mapper but NOT case sensitive) which lets me deserialize an object without having to loop through object keys and manually extract values or write a ton of boilerplate code

I want to parse the JSON to a single unified object schema, say { property }, so I can access it without lots of conditions checking for variations of the name

Comment: @CertainPerformance Updated last paragraph to hopefully answer your question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480570/json-stringify-change-the-case-of-the-key

Comment: Prior to running JSON.parse(), `.toUpperCase()` or `.toLowerCase()` the entire JSON string. Then JSON.parse() it. That should create consistent case.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Yes, but that will change the values to lowercase in addition to the keys. However if they're all numeric, as in the example, that's the best approach.

Comment: @RandyCasburn because that would change the case of the values as well??

Comment: OK, ok pile on already :-). - was looking at the OP's example

Comment: @eoleary Well this exists, probably worth a shot: https://www.npmjs.com/package/normalize-object

Comment: @jmcgriz interesting! Ii'll take a peak at it

Comment: @georg Your link addresses `stringify`, but OP is asking about how to `parse`

Comment: @georg no offense, but that linked post doesnt solve crap. The solution only transforms the first character from uppercase to lowercase, it doesn't fix the underlying problem.

Comment: @CertainPerformance: the accepted answer over there contains JSON.parse code which is basically the same as yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to write your custom `reviver` function, as the second parameter to `JSON.parse`, that transforms plain objects' keys to lower case:

```js
const json = `{"Property": 5,"inner":{"Foo":"foo"}}`;
const obj = JSON.parse(
  json,
  (_, val) => {
    if (Array.isArray(val) || typeof val !== 'object') {
      return val;
    }
    return Object.entries(val).reduce((a, [key, val]) => {
      a[key.toLowerCase()] = val;
      return a;
    }, {});
  }
);
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: This feels unsatisfactory, but its probably the best way to do it suggested so far

Comment: Can you explain what seems off about it? It's only a few lines of code, doesn't require a library, and (I think) will work properly for any correctly formatted input JSON. Unless there's an input for which it doesn't work, I'm pretty sure I would prefer this sort of implementation to anything else

Comment: I agree with @eoleary, it would have been easier if this was provided out of the box. But you're right, it does work. Only you should add a `if (!val) { return val; }` check at the top in case of `null` returned from the backend.

Answer (score 0):

A more modern option would be:

Note that original keys being the same but with different case would be merged and the most recent entry will be retained.

```js
const toLowerCaseObject = (input) => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(input).map(([a,b]) => [a.toLocaleLowerCase(), b]));

console.log(JSON.stringify(toLowerCaseObject({A: 11, b: 12, B: 1})));
```